# why the auto_renew_adam_id and expiration_intent is null when received apple server notification

Tags: in-app-purchase

Now I am develop an in app purchase. I write a endpont to receive [apple server notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications). but now I found the `auto_renew_adam_id` and `expiration_intent`  is null when received request from apple server, this is my receive entity define:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "auto_renew_adam_id")
@JsonProperty("auto_renew_adam_id")
private String autoRenewAdamId;


@ApiModelProperty(value = "expiration_intent")
@JsonProperty("expiration_intent")
private Integer expirationIntent;
```

is it actually be null or my code not right? apple doc did not tell the value should be nul or not.

Comment: I am not sure about the adam id, but `expiration intent` is only set, when the subscription expired. Did you already receive production notifications, maybe the adam_id isn't set in sandbox notification?

Comment: I did not know, now I am in sandbox environment. @PaulSchröder I think the adam id should not be null accord the apple doc, but I do not know why it is actually be null..